# How to pipe in to for loop elixir

Tags: for-loop, syntax, elixir

If I wanted to pipe into a case, I would do the following:

```
amount
|> calculate
|> case do
  1 -> "one"
  2 -> "two"
  _ -> "many"
end
```

Would it be possible to pipe into a `for` loop in a similar way, something like:

```
amounts
|> calculate
|> for do
  IO.inspect &1
end
```

or

```
amounts
|> calculate
|> Kernel.for(&IO.inspect/1)
```

I am aware that I could use the `Enum` methods, but I am more curious about how the above could work.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `for` is a comprehension, not a loop in it’s regular meaning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. The reason it works with `case` is that `case` is a macro whose first argument is a value and the second is the match clauses. `for` on the other hand has only one argument which includes all clauses and the do block:

```
iex(1)> quote do
...(1)>   for a <- 1..10, b <- 1..10, do: a + b
...(1)> end
{:for, [],
 [
   {:<-, [],
    [{:a, [], Elixir}, {:.., [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 10]}]},
   {:<-, [],
    [{:b, [], Elixir}, {:.., [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 10]}]},
   [
     do: {:+, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
      [{:a, [], Elixir}, {:b, [], Elixir}]}
   ]
 ]}
```

(As you can see, `for` takes onea argument which is the whole value `a <- 1..10, b <- 1..10, do: a + b`.)

The best you can do with `for` is to pipe into an anonymous function. It isn't pretty but I have used this a couple of times when I wanted the functionality of `for` that isn't supported by `Enum.each` or `Enum.map` (multiple clauses, inline filters, `into`, etc).

```
iex(2)> 1..5 |> (fn x -> for(i <- x, do: IO.puts(i)) end).()
1
2
3
4
5
[:ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok]
```